# Add Multiple Control Points in Canvas Shape

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

I have made canvas Shapes(squares) in kinetic js having 4 control points on each of their vertices.A user can click and drag these control points and distort the shape any way he/she pleases.The fiddle link is

http://jsfiddle.net/Lucy1/opsy1pn9/2/

The corresponding js code is

```
   var room = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: w,
    height: h,
    stroke: "blue",
    fill: 'red',
    drawFunc: function (context) {
        var x = this.x();
        var y = this.y();
        var w = this.width();
        var h = this.height();
        var tlX = this.anchorTL.x();
        var tlY = this.anchorTL.y();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(tlX, tlY);
        // top
        context.bezierCurveTo(x + w / 3, y, x + w * 2 / 3, y, this.anchorTR.x(), this.anchorTR.y());
        // right
        context.bezierCurveTo(x + w, y + h / 3, x + w, y + h * 2 / 3, this.anchorBR.x(), this.anchorBR.y());
        // bottom
        context.bezierCurveTo(x + w * 2 / 3, y + h, x + w / 3, y + h, this.anchorBL.x(), this.anchorBL.y());
        // left
        context.bezierCurveTo(x, y + h * 2 / 3, x, y + h / 3, tlX, tlY);

        context.closePath();
        context.fillStrokeShape(this);
    }
});
```

The problem is that i want to add more control points on each square edge. I want the canvas shape to look like this

[image: Control Points]

The square above has 2 control points on each side in addition to 4 control points in the vertices, so each square has total 12 points .I want the squares in the js fiddle also to have 12 control points each.I can't understand where and what modifications to make so that each of the canvas squares has 12 control points..Please Help..

Comment: You already have the technique you need.  Just add additional anchors for the 8 missing control points and then plug the anchor x,y into the Bezier curves. ;-)

Comment: @markE I tried adding control points in the mid-point of each line by adding additional anchors and plugging them into the Bezier Curve, but the mid-point control points are not moving with the line like the vertex points..The js fiddle is  http://jsfiddle.net/Lucy1/opsy1pn9/4/

Comment: Each Bezier curve has 4 control points so you need 4 anchors. Control points: (1) starting point (2) mid point influencing the starting point (3) mid point influencing the ending point (4) ending point.